# Xsl Transformation Changes <i></i> to <i />

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tags, transformation

I am trying to transform the following Xsl stylesheet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/TestPage" xml:space="preserve" >
    <ul>
      <li class="first complete-tab">
        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>Step 1
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Step 2
      </li>
      <li class="last">Step 3</li>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The code I'm using is as follows.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xslFile = "C:\\Projects\\Test.xsl";

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlElement rootElement = doc.CreateElement("TestPage");
        doc.AppendChild(rootElement);

        string result = TransformDoc(doc, xslFile);
    }

    private static string TransformDoc(XmlDocument doc, string transformPath)
    {
        return TransformDoc(doc.CreateNavigator(), transformPath);
    }

    static string TransformDoc(XPathNavigator nav, string transformPath, XsltArgumentList args = null)
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        string result = "A transformation Error Has Occurred";

        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(buffer))
        using (XmlTextWriter xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {

            XslCompiledTransform oTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            XsltSettings oSettings = new XsltSettings(false, true);

            oTransform.Load(transformPath, oSettings, null);
            if (args == null)
                oTransform.Transform(nav, xmlWriter);
            else
                oTransform.Transform(nav, args, xmlWriter);
            result = buffer.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The code above transforms the Xsl file, however I'm finding that I'm not getting the desired output.

The result is

```
<ul>
  <li class="first complete-tab">
    <i class="fa fa-check-circle" />Step 1
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" />Step 2
  </li>
  <li class="last">Step 3</li>
</ul>
```

For `<i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>Step 1`, I am getting the following `<i class="fa fa-check-circle" />` which is breaking my display because of the closing the tag.

Comment: Try adding `<xsl:output method="html" />` to your stylesheet

Comment: @TimC I added as you suggested, and updated my question, but still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/output-options-on-the-xslcompiledtransform-class it says...

> If your style sheet uses the xsl:output element and the output type is
>   an XmlWriter object, you should use the
>   XslCompiledTransform.OutputSettings property when you create the
>   XmlWriter object. The XslCompiledTransform.OutputSettings property
>   returns an XmlWriterSettings object that contains information derived
>   from the xsl:output element of a compiled style sheet. This
>   XmlWriterSettings object can be passed to the XmlWriter.Create method
>   to create an XmlWriter object with the correct settings.

So, you need to use an `XmlWriter` here and pass the OutputSettings for the compiled transform to it when you create it....

```
    static string TransformDoc(XPathNavigator nav, string transformPath, XsltArgumentList args = null)
    {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        string result = "A transformation Error Has Occurred";

        XslCompiledTransform oTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        XsltSettings oSettings = new XsltSettings(false, true);
        oTransform.Load(transformPath, oSettings, null);

        using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(buffer))
        using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, oTransform.OutputSettings))
        {
            if (args == null)
                oTransform.Transform(nav, xmlWriter);
            else
                oTransform.Transform(nav, args, xmlWriter);
            result = buffer.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }
```